# Integral of $\frac{x^3-2}{x^3-x}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

As the title says, I need some help with this function:
$$ \int\frac{x^3-2}{x^3-x}$$
I tried it with different versions/forms of the function to get it with substitution or partiel integration:

$$ \int\frac{x^3-2}{x^3-x} = \frac{x^3-2}{x(x-1)(x+1)} = \frac{x^3}{x^3-x} - \frac{2}{x^3-x}$$

Do you have some advice?

Comment: $\int\big(\frac a x + \frac b {x+1} + \frac c {x-1} +d\big)$

Comment: Try long division

Answer (score 6):

try this 
$$\frac{x^3-2}{x^3-x} = 1  + \frac{x-2}{x^3-x}$$
Now use partial fraction.

Comment: Why is it the same?

Comment: take LCM and see

Comment: @Giesi what is $(x^3-2)-(x^3-x)$?

Comment: Thx I get it ;)